# I would like to alert message while another user is editing or update data in wordpress admin panel, what should i do?

Tags: php

My question is that when one user is editing and have another user is editing the site too , I wanna get one alert message to tell the user that now who is editing.

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress displays warning as shown in below screenshot when you try to edit post/page which is being edited by other.

[image: Wordpress Warning]